# Does gnome-core includes window manager and display server?

Tags: debian, display-manager

So I've freshly installed Debian without the tasksel option to install a desktop environment. I wonder how it works that if I install the package gnome-core, everything works fine, even without installing a display server like Wayland? Or does gnome-core include window manager and display server? Is it all preinstalled in Debian? After https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/gnome-core *gdm3* is included, does that display manager includes the display server and window manager? **Sorry but I'm very confused and just want to know how it works that I just have to install gnome-core and everything works out after a fresh install of the latest Debian stable. What is installed from beginning (without ticking the desktop environment option during installation) and what does gnome-core adds from the following components?**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gnome-core`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/gnome-core) is a meta-package providing

> the official “core” modules of the GNOME desktop.

It does this by depending on all the components required for the core GNOME desktop environment, including `gdm3` (the login manager) and `gnome-shell` (which implements Wayland). It also recommends a number of packages which will be pulled in in a default configuration, including the X.org X server.

From your diagram, its dependencies include the display server, window manager and graphical interface.